# How to print a list of lists as a simple string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a sample data like :

```
[[[['D', 'X'], 'True', '7.6S', '12', '12', '-1', 'False', '1239217113'], '12', ['6.1D', '6.2D', '6.3D', '6.4D']],
[[['D', 'X3'], 'True', '30.6S', '12', '12', '-1', 'False', '2080709342'], '12', ['6.1D', '6.2D', '6.3D', '6.4D']]]
```

Its list comprising of smaller lists and strings .

I want to print it to a file like :

```
D,X,True,7.6S,12,12,-1,False,1239217113,12,6.1D,6.2D,6.3D,6.4D
```

Is there any built in function to do this ? any smart way to achieve this ?

Comment: flatten each item, then write it using the `csv` module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using generator :

```
l = [[[['D', 'X'], 'True', '7.6S', '12', '12', '-1', 'False', '1239217113'], '12', ['6.1D', '6.2D', '6.3D', '6.4D']],[[['D', 'X3'], 'True', '30.6S', '12', '12', '-1', 'False', '2080709342'], '12', ['6.1D', '6.2D', '6.3D', '6.4D']]]

def flatten(l):
    for e in l:
        if isinstance(e, list):
            yield from flatten(e)
        else:
            yield e

with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    print(','.join(flatten(l)), file=f)
```

Comment: wow, thanks ! worked like a charm. I couldnot get the keyword-'flatten' otherwise wouldn't have posted the question.

Comment: lil bit out of context , accidenty i included the 'with open..' call in the api flatten , called flatten() from appropriate place. The api wouldn't get called itself. any reasons

Answer (score 1):

```
data=[[[['D', 'X'], 'True', '7.6S', '12', '12', '-1', 'False', '1239217113'], '12', ['6.1D', '6.2D', '6.3D', '6.4D']],[[['D', 'X3'], 'True', '30.6S', '12', '12', '-1', 'False', '2080709342'], '12', ['6.1D', '6.2D', '6.3D', '6.4D']]]
f={ list: lambda x: x, str: lambda x: [x] }
while True:
    data2 = sum( map(lambda y: f[type(y)](y), data ), [] )
    if data2 == data:
        break
    data = data2
print(data)
```

Comment: Took me long to understand how it works. I kinda like this strange workaround (but would never use it)

Comment: Yeah it's not really readable - I was trying to figure out if its possible to do in one line. Think there might be a way with functools.reduce

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy.

```
lists = [[['D', 'X3'], 'True', '30.6S', '12', '12', '-1', 'False', '2080709342'], '12', ['6.1D', '6.2D', '6.3D', '6.4D']]

str_list = str(lists)
result = str_list.replace('[','').replace(']','')

with open('name.txt','w') as FILE:
    FILE.write(result)
```

Comment: This is a really dangerous solution. Imagine you have inside your list elements containing ']' or '[' character like this  : [[4,2], 'Hello[World]']

Comment: thats true, but its dangerous in itself to put these symbols in the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_all_elements(big_list):
    for i in big_list:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            # print(i)
            print_all_elements(i)
        else:
            print(i)


print_all_elements([[[['D', 'X'], 'True', '7.6S', '12', '12', '-1', 'False', '1239217113'],
                     '12', ['6.1D', '6.2D', '6.3D', '6.4D']],
                    [[['D', 'X3'], 'True', '30.6S', '12', '12', '-1', 'False', '2080709342'],
                     '12', ['6.1D', '6.2D', '6.3D', '6.4D']]])
```